# c++ cout like c printf

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    float f = 12.f;
    printf("%.2f", f);
}
```

output 12.00

how can I achieve that with c++ stl using cout ?

Tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float f = 12.f;
    cout << setprecision(2) << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you change your example to the answer? I cannot see a difference between your not working (?) code and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you have invalid syntax. `12f` should be `12.f`. or `12.0f`. Secondly, in order to display your number in fixed-point notation, use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). i.e:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
// <ios> header not needed
int main() 
{
    float f = 12.f;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: A literal with `f` suffix but no decimal point is not a valid float literal? Damn, I did not know that.